# Select a variable name without the dollar symbol

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-plugin

What is the way in IntelliJ IDEA to select a variable without the dollar (`$`) sign?

I have the following content is a `*.sh` file:

```
println "say something: %s" "$HELLO"
```

Or this in a `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN set -ux; \
    println "say something: %s" "$HELLO"; \
    echo "$HELLO"
```

When I double click on the `HELLO` string, then IDEA selects the whole content between the brackets (`$HELLO`). But in my case I have to select more often only the variable name without `$`. Selecting the variable name char by char is so time consuming, especially if you have to repeat this often.

Is there any way to modify the select behavior somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Enable these 2 options:

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Use "CamelHumps" words
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click

Comment: That works like a charm with `$HELLO` but if the variable contains underscore(s) unfortunately, it does not: `$HELLO_WORLD`.

Comment: Feature request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA. Make sure to provide a use case when you want to copy the the variable name without `$`.